# Django - how to make ImageField/FileField optional?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename, blank=True)
```

When I use `ImageField(blank=True)` and do not select image into admin form, an exception occurs.

In django code you can see this:

```
class FieldFile(File):
   ....

    def _require_file(self):
        if not self:
            raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)

    def _get_file(self):
        self._require_file()
        ...
```

Django trac has ticket #13327 about this problem, but seems it can't be fixed soon. How to make these field optional?

Comment: did you find a solution, it seems that i have the same issue now

Answer (score 49):

`blank=True` should work. If this attribute, which is `False` by default, is set to `True` then it will allow entry of an empty value.

I have the following class in my article app:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
        imagename = models.TextField()
        articleimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

I make use of the above class in another class by using the `ManyToManyField` relationship:

```
class Article(models.Model):
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=130)
        title = models.TextField()
        photo = models.ManyToManyField(
            Photo, related_name='photos', blank=True)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User)
        body = models.TextField()
        categories = models.ManyToManyField(
            Category, related_name='articles', null=True)
```

I want to make images in my articles optional, so `blank=True` in

```
photo = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name='photos', blank=True)
```

is necessary. This allows me to create an article without any images if I want to.

Are you using class `Product` in any relationship? If so, make sure to set `blank=True` in the relationship you are using.

Comment: why aren't you using null for the image?

Comment: Trying to do that, I get `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__app_idea.image`

Answer (score 22):

Set `null=True` (see [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null))

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: null=True is scary, blank=True is enough because ImageField/FileField are actually CharFields underneath...

Comment: null=True doesn't do anything for FileField or ImageField https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10244

Answer (score 3):

If **'optional'** means that you want to be able to disregard the image field altogether. Then `blank=True`, so do the trick. However, if you are still getting the same error, then this means that you are using it's `url` either in the template somewhere or you are trying to open the path of the image in `models.py` or `views.py` ( may be to resize the image or some other backend preprocessing).
That is why it is always suggested to use `try` - `catch` block while handling files.

Comment: Thanks! this fixed my issue, turns out I have a method in my models.py that resizes the uploaded image before saving to the database and its opening the path of that image.