# Django: The correct way to make FileField optional?

Tags: python, database, django, django-south, database-migration

When setting a new FileField in a model to blank=True, it asks to specify a default value for existing rows when running a schemamigration. This would lead me to believe that I should set null = True which has been addressed

Here: [How to make FileField in django optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940308/how-to-make-filefield-in-django-optional)

And Here: [Django - how to make ImageField/FileField optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677637/django-how-to-make-imagefield-filefield-optional)

However, the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null explicitly say that it is not recommended to set the default to null.

If this is the case, what are the alternatives for setting a default and making a FileField optional without using null?

Comment: Are you using South for your migration? Are you planning to update the FileField with real values after the migration? If so, you could plan for another migration afterward to change the FileField to null=False once all your values are in place.

Comment: I am using south. Some will have FileField value, some will not. That's why I would like to make it optional. If i set null=false for existing rows and then changed it for another migration, it would become optional for new objects created with the FileField in the future? If that's the case, I guess it's a workaround.

Comment: I think you are fine using blank=True, null=True as the accepted answer states in your first link. The docs suggest using an empty string for the default value but that is just a Django convention. This is done for CharFields and string-based fields. Since the FileField is really a string path to the stored file, I can see why it **may** be good to use an empty string...all your values would be strings. However, I'd kinda prefer Null for FileField and empty string for CharField, the fact that the FileField is a string path is really an implementation detail. Just my opinion :)

Comment: Also, either way you go, make sure to document the behaviour in the model class docstring.

Comment: It's worth noting that null=True doesn't do anything in the db: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10244. I'd avoid using it on FileFields.